# Is there any other way to get the aggregation query execution time metrics in MongoDB atlas?

Tags: mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-atlas, execution-time, mongodb-explain

Having read that [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas/faq) is high performant, I'm eager to know the Execution Time differences between my aggregation queries run on my local MongoDB Server and on my MongoDB Atlas instance. Hence I have set up a M0(Free Tier) MongoDB Atlas Database.

In my local MongoDB Server, I can see the aggregation query execution time using the following command:

```
db.collection.explain("executionStats").aggregate([
{ $match....},
{ $facet...},
...])
```

My collection contains 10k documents with nested arrays and complex aggregation query.Execution time is almost 30 seconds.

But when it comes to MongoDB Atlas, it is specified in the [doc](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/free-shared-limitations/) that Atlas M0 Free Tier clusters do not support the helper methods like `explain()` for the aggregation command. So I cannot see the execution time.

Is there any other way to get the aggregation query execution time metrics without upgrading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done simply using a Javascript function.

```
d = new Date; 
db.coll.aggregate(...); 
print(new Date - d + 'ms')
```